# Practical integration along vertical lines

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, mellin-transform

I want to ask a practical integration and I hope the answer could be a line by line form to for me to understand.

Consider complex integration. Assume the integration is consist of a vertical line $K: [c-i\infty,c+i\infty]$, and enclose it by large radius circle $L$ at the infinity.
Then complex analysis is teaching us
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint_{L+K} f(z) dz =\frac{1}{2\pi i } \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} f(z) dz + \frac{1}{2\pi i } \int_{L} f(z) dz
$$
On the left hand side, one can evaluate it by residue. On the RHS people usually evaluate the integration over large radius $K$ and find it either vanishing or some finite answer (See Chapter 2 of E. Elizalde, S. D. Odintsov, A. Romeo, Andrei A. Bytsenko, S. Zerbini - Zeta regularization techniques with applications-World Scientific (1994) for an example of finite answer for the infinity integration).

In short, I feel I lack the knowledge of how to do integration on the the vertial line $K$. I only know to do it by computing the residue and subtracting the integration from the infinity. But I assume some computation should be straightforwardly doable for the vertical straightline.
This is very common in Mellin transformation.

For example: Cahen–Mellin integral (I do not find the resources for doing this line by line) $$
e^{-z} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma(s) z^{-s} ds
$$
I want to see the integration on the RHS can be evaluated like take $s=c+i t$.
Then
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Gamma(c+ it) z^{-c - it} i(dt) = \text{Re}() + \text{Im} ()
$$
and compute for each of them. Show me this is indeed $e^{-z}$ and independent of $c$. Is this possible? I can also accept other examples.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking, but it seems that you are asking about if the change of variable works for line integrals? Of course it does

Comment: The point is that usually $\int_K$ is hard, and contour integration makes $\int_{L+K}$ and the residues easy. Though in this case I'm suspicious since $\Gamma$ blows up faster than exponentially, so you'd have to work hard to convince me the large arc integral decays or tends to something sensible

Comment: It's not independent of $c$ since the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}_x\left[e^{-x}\right](s)=\int\limits_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\, x^{s-1} \, dx=\Gamma (s)$$ is only valid for $\Re(s)>0$.

Comment: I am asking to do the integration over K as calculus exercise. Without using the residue, and interation at the infinity. On one hand, one can compute integration over K, while on the other hand one know it is equal to residue minus integration over infnity. One can check two computations equal by doing them independently right？So my puzzle is how to do the integration over K directly. The last formula I wrote down in the question is an integration problem. How to do it step by step?